# Getting backbone routing to work properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've looked around at the various tutorials and documentation, and I'm still having some trouble getting the backbone router to work. I'm running the code in my Sites folder on OS X (the url is `http://localhost/~plebrun`). Neither `http://localhost/~plebrun/#foo` nor `http://localhost/~plebrun/#type/books` works. Thoughts?

(Note: the data_* variables contain json data)

```
  /****************************/
  /********** MODELS **********/
  /****************************/

  var Category = Backbone.Model.extend();
  var Phrase = Backbone.Model.extend();

  /****************************/
  /******** COLLECTIONS *******/
  /****************************/

  var Type = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Category
  });

  /****************************/
  /********** VIEWS ***********/
  /****************************/

  var TypeView = Backbone.View.extend({   /* a Type is a list of Categories */
    el: $('#categories'),
    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      var ul_list = "";
      _(this.collection.models).each(function(category) {
        ul_list += '<li><a href="/category/' + category.get('id') + '"><h1>' + category.get('en') + '</h1><p>' + category.get('es') + '</p></a></li>';
      });
      $(this.el).append(ul_list);
    }
  });

  /****************************/
  /********* ROUTER ***********/
  /****************************/

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "/type/:src":          "showType",
      "/foo":                "foo"
    },

    locate_data: {
      "books":          data_books,
      "conversations":  data_conversations,
      "phrases": data_phrases
    },

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'showType');
    },

    foo: function() {
      alert("foo")
    },

    showType: function(src) {
      console.log(src);
      var types = new Type(this.locate_data[src]);
      new TypeView({ collection: types });
    }
  });

  /****************************/
  /********** INIT ************/
  /****************************/

  var foo = new AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/~plebrun/"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out routing wasn't the problem... I had neglected to wrap the code in $('document').ready(). I didn't think I needed to since the scrip tag reference to the js file was included at the bottom of the web page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first slash at the beginning of the route. So the routes should be

```
routes: {
  "type/:src":          "showType",
  "foo":                "foo"
}
```

Comment: I would also really recommend looking into a templating engine for your html rendering, the underscore template functionality that comes with backbone should be good enough here. You could get rid of the smelly code code in TypeView.render,

Comment: Good advice, and eventually I'll use Handlebars.js - I just wanted to get something working first. Unfortunately removing the starting forward slash didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what goes wrong here. I would recommend testing without the pushState (not sure if your server redirects /~plebrun/foo to the same page) and running at the root of the server, so without the root parameter for history.

Answer (score 1):

What doesn't work? Does the app initialize? Does the URL change when you click a link?

One thing you need to be aware of when using pushState, is that when you click on a working link, the page will be requested from the server. In other words, you need to hijack links so that backbone's router processes them instead of calling the server. To achieve this, you can use a function like this one:

```
MyApp.Support = {
  // navigate to CRUD actions when the links are clicked
  navigateLink: function (e) {
    var target = $(e.currentTarget);

    if( ! target.attr('data-method')){ // don't change delete links
      e.preventDefault();
      AppRouter.navigate(target.attr('href'), { trigger: true });
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you can have something like this in your view:

```
events: {
  'click a[data-method!="destroy"]': "navigateLink"
}
```

In other words, when you click on a link, Backbone's router will navigate to it, instead of fetching the page from the server.